# Does "one non-Logos card" on Phase Shift limit me, or just enable me?

Tags: keyforge

If I play 2 Phase Shifts in the same turn, can I play two non-Logos cards? If I play Wild Wormhole, resulting in playing a non-Logos card, can I still use Phase Shift to play another non-Logos card?

[image: Phase Shift - Action; Play: You may play one non-Logos card this turn.]
[image: Wild Wormhole - Action; 1 aember; Play: Play the top card of your deck.]

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't limit, it only enables. For every Phase Shift you play, you're going to be able to play one non-Logos card that turn. Here are some additional quotes from emails sent by Brad Andres (developer at FFG):

> The Wild Wormhole is creating it own play permission for
>   the card it is playing from the top of the deck separate from the play
>   permission that the Phase shift is creating. Meaning that you can
>   still play a non-Logos card from playing the phase shift.

FFG also addressed this in [this video](https://youtu.be/ESETHb99U40?t=1045).